# Plotting Scatterplot Matrix or Correlation matrix or both?

Tags: classification, data-visualization, data-mining, dataset

I have a problem where I want to use a classifier for it. So I defined a set of features and created a dataset. Now I want to generate some plots to understand the features. I came across the Scatterplot Matrix or the Correlation Matrix, but I'm so confused about if they are the same thing or not.

1 - [Visualizing correlation matrices](http://glowingpython.blogspot.de/2012/10/visualizing-correlation-matrices.html)

2- [Scatterplot Matrices](http://www.r-bloggers.com/scatterplot-matrices/)

So my questions:

- Are they the same thing?
- Does plotting both make sense? i.e. each plot convey a different message?

Comment: You don't have to choose. Good plotting wrappers for correlation matrices, such as http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/correlograms.html ,  will happily give you the option to plot the scatters in one of the diagonals, and the coefficients in the.

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not the same thing.

The correlation matrix shows the strength of each correlation, but correlation is a measure of the *linear* relationship between two variables.

The scatterplot matrix is a matrix of scatterplots; a scatterplot lets you assess *all* the relationships between two variables.

The downsides of the latter are: 1) It's more work  2) It doesn't necessarily get you a single number summary (although some interesting work is being done) 3) You can't fit as big a matrix on the page.